# Parse + Heroku Query 500 Error

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I used Parse's CLI with the new Heroku integration to create the scaffold NodeJS project (`parse new`).

The example cloud function it gives you is:

```
// Hello
Parse.Cloud.define('hello', function(request, response) {    

  response.success('Hello world! ' + (request.params.a + request.params.b));

});
```

I can hit this route with the following CURL command and everything works fine:

```
curl -X POST \
 -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: b8qPYS4SLSz0WoSWXlWeQosmF2jJPUPydetg3esR" \
 -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: TOJLbfbNXSQcBdDVnU0MnKVu7SyamQvZmorHL5iD" \
 -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
 -d '{"a": "Adventurous ", "b": "Parser"}' \
 https://api.parse.com/1/functions/hello
```

But then I added a new Class to my Parse Data, inserted a row, and tried to query & return the results. I keep getting `{"code":143,"error":"Invalid webhook response status: 500 Internal Server Error"}` as the response.

I'm fairly certain it is not my code that is the problem and am guessing there is some configuration step or something I'm missing.

Here is my modified Parse function:

```
// Hello
Parse.Cloud.define('hello', function(request, response) {    
  var query = Parse.Query("Favorites");

  query.find({ useMasterKey: true }).then(
    function(results) {
      response.success('win');
    }, function() {
      response.error('fail');
    });

});
```

And a picture of my Parse Class with the inserted row:

[image]

I have Googled the error and can't find any good answers only poorly worded questions. I'm completely at a loss here. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: listing KEYS in forums not good idea!

Comment: goto parse dashboard and verify users may create new classes. create new class in the dashboard if necessary. add rows to it . verify in dashboard. call the new class from the CLI (GET on REST call to cloud Function ). then GET them from Node layer using a query. and it should all work

Comment: They're public keys there is nothing secret about them. The steps you are describing I've already done as shown in my well annotated post.

Comment: I have a very similar issue @TylerBuchea. I will be digging the docs. Please let me know if you find a solution.

Comment: So I decided to not use Heroku and got it to work.. Not sure what's up with the heroku server

Comment: I've been checking up on this and I'll definitely let you know if I find a solution. I'm considering dropping Parse and using a Heroku PostgreSQL instance for my data. Glad you were able to work out some sort of solution too.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Parse is wrong initialised on register-webhooks.js post deploy script:
    Parse.initialize(process.env.PARSE_APP_ID, "unused", process.env.PARSE_MASTER_KEY);

And without second parameter (JavaScript Key) you can't execute any Parse.Query from cloud functions.

So my solution is:

1. Add new `PARSE_JS_KEY` to Heroku Config Variables (value is JavaScript Key from Parse->Settings->Keys)
2. In server.js file add line:

   `Parse.initialize(process.env.PARSE_APP_ID, process.env.PARSE_JS_KEY, process.env.PARSE_MASTER_KEY);`

before `require('./cloud/main.js');`

PS: Place `process.env.PARSE_JS_KEY` directly in register-webhooks.js initializer does not work.

Comment: You are RIGHT ON! I can't believe a brand new generated app could overlook something like this?