# Parse + Heroku Add Object 500 Error

Tags: javascript, curl, heroku, parse-platform, cloud

I have deployed the following Parse Cloud Code:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("hello", function(request, response) {
  response.success("Hello world! " + (request.params.a + request.params.b));
});
```

This works fine when I do the following cURL command

```
curl -X POST   
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: {APP_ID}"   
-H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: {API_KEY}"  
-H "Content-Type: application/json"  
-d '{"a":"Adventurous ", "b": "Parser"}'      
https://api.parse.com/1/functions/hello
```

I then deployed the following code to create an object:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("addObject", function(request, response) {
  var MyObject = Parse.Object.extend("myclass");
  var myObject = new MyObject();

  myObject.set('type', 'cloud');

  myObject.save(null, {
    success: function(myObject) {
      response.success("saved the object");
    },
    error: function(myObject, error) {
      response.error("didn't save the object. Error=" + error.message);
    }
  });
});
```

and when I run the following cURL command:

```
curl -X POST   
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: {APP_ID}"   
-H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: {API_KEY}"  
-H "Content-Type: application/json"  
-d '{"a":"Super Adventurous ", "b": "Parser"}'      
https://api.parse.com/1/functions/addObject
```

the following error is logged:

```
E2015-11-07T08:13:19.227Z]vWEB Ran cloud function addObject with:
  Input: {}
  Result: Invalid webhook response status: 500 Internal Server Error
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Not sure what the error was here. I figured I'd try to use Parse instead of Heroku if something was up with the server and got it to work via Parse instead.

Comment: I found some solution. See my answer: [Invalid webhook response status: 500 Internal Server Error"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33458741/parse-heroku-query-500-error/33741232#33741232)